# issues with calculating Median

Tags: excel

Here is my data

```html
10 A
12 A
14 B
15 B
15 C
11 D
12 D
10 B
11 A
```

I want to select A and C from Column B and then calculate the median based on column A.

I have used this function

`=MEDIAN(IF(B1:B9="A",B1:B9="C",A1:A9))`

But I got a wrong Number. Can we solve this issues? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you have three answers below.  If you used one of them then please mark that one as correct.  It is something only you can do.  It will close this question as answered.  Click on the green check mark by the one answer to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, entered as an array formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while you hit `Enter`

```
=MEDIAN(IF($B$1:$B$10={"A","C"},$A$1:$A$10))
```

The `IF` function returns an array of either the appropriate value in A1:A10, or FALSE.  And the MEDIAN function will ignore the logical values, since they are produced by a function, and not manually entered.

Here is a screen shot showing the data and the result.  You can see the formula in the formula bar: (Note that the braces `{...}` around the formula are **NOT** added manually.  They will be added by Excel when you confirm the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`.  With regard to the array constant, however, those braces you do type in manually.

[image]

Comment: Nice.  Moments after I express my doubt that it's possible.  This is elegant, and seems to work when I try it

Comment: @Baronz `MEDIAN` is a bit odd.  It will ignore logical values if they are produced by a function, as does the `IF` function in my solution.  However, if you manually enter a logical value, it will use it.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  When I change row A6 to 500, your median changes, but mine stays the same.  Yours is still counting the rows he is trying to exclude.

Comment: @Baronz When I change A6 to 500, my median remains 11.5

Comment: Ron, It seems it work, But I got the median in C1:C9, Can we see it in a cell only

Comment: I don't understand what you have done.  If I enter the formula in, for example, C1, that is where I see the result.  Did you enter the formula in multiple cells?  If so, why?

Comment: @Baronz  Did you array-enter the formula?  I don't see the braces `{...}` around the formula in the formula bar.

Comment: @USER2313456 You may not have been flagged with my last response.  I will add a screenshot showing the data and my formula, so you can see it showing up in only a single cell.

Comment: @Baronz  I don't understand how you are getting a result of `12` in that screenshot.  Can you upload the workbook so I can look at it more closely?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - in that screenshot, F5 **could** have a custom number format of `0` but I don't get the lack of array formula **{** and **}** either unless F2 had been tapped and the cursor is in the formula bar (with allow edit directly in cells turned off) but that *should* show the precedents with colored borders.

Comment: @Jeeped  My thoughts also.  That's why I would like to examine the workbook, to see what's going on.  Although, my recollection is that with older versions of Excel (e.g 2007-), the precedents did not get highlighted with colored borders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this aggregate Function:

```
=AGGREGATE(17,6,$A$1:$A$500/(($B$1:$B$500 = "A")+($B$1:$B$500 = "C")),2)
```

This is entered as normal formula. It is a non CSE array formula.

[image]

Comment: I understand that the 2nd quartile is the Median, but when I try to use the Median function directly (argument #12), I get a #VALUE! error.  Can you explain that? `=AGGREGATE(12,6,$A$1:$A$500/(($B$1:$B$500 = "A")+($B$1:$B$500 = "C")))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that is because in the first criteria, anything under 14 cannot use arrays as the third criteria, but has to use direct references.  That is why it was needed to use 17.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  Did not see that in the documentation.  Recently upgraded from 2007 to 2016 and `AGGREGATE` is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it all in one equation.  I think you need a new column to create an intermediate value, then solve it.

[image]

I put this equation in column C (and dragged it down the column):

```
=IF(OR(B1="A",B1="B"),A1,"")
```

And then I tested the values by calculating the Mean (average), Median (middle number), and Mode (most common value).  Because there are 6 values, Excel takes the middle of the two.

Here are my equations for column F:

```
=AVERAGE(C1:C9)
=MEDIAN(C1:C9)
=MODE(C1:C19)
```

Here is the Microsoft link talking about why the "Median" may be a value between two on the list:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MEDIAN-function-D0916313-4753-414C-8537-CE85BDD967D2

Comment: I knew this method, but I am interested to run it on function. Is it possible to run it in a function

Comment: I doubt there is a method without some serious excel trickery, because you need the "tally" of values too.  Your original set has 9 values, but you want to do a median only only 6 of them.